# Plotting a line over several graphs

Tags: python, plot, numerical, matplotlib

I don't know how this thing is called, or even how to describe it, so the title may be a little bit misleading.


The first attached graph was created with pyplot. I would like to draw a straight line that goes through all graphs instead of the three red dot I currently use. Is it possible in pyplot? Second image is what I am looking for.
[image: Currently]
[image: What I am looking for]

Comment: How do you determine where to take red points?

Comment: @Sword22 All graphs have the same x-axis. Red points are basically a list of x-axis values.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can pull this off by turning clipping off for the relevant lines.  There's probably a cleaner way to do this -- you might be able to draw lines on the main frame directly -- but the following worked for me:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from numpy import arange, sin, cos

xx = arange(100)
cut = (xx > 0) & (xx % 17 == 0)
y1 = sin(xx)
y2 = (xx**2) % 2.0+cos(xx+0.5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(xx, y1, c="blue",zorder=1)
ax1.scatter(xx[cut], y1[cut], c="red",zorder=2)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(xx, y2, c="green",zorder=1)
ax2.scatter(xx[cut], y2[cut], c="red",zorder=2)

for x in xx[cut]:
    ax1.axvline(x=x,ymin=-1.2,ymax=1,c="red",linewidth=2,zorder=0, clip_on=False)
    ax2.axvline(x=x,ymin=0,ymax=1.2,c="red",linewidth=2, zorder=0,clip_on=False)

plt.draw()
fig.savefig('pic.png')
```

With a bit more work you could modify the line drawing to handle the general case of multiple subplot windows, but I'm profoundly lazy. :^)

[image: example of cross-subplot vertical lines]

Answer (score 12):

Relevant documentation:
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline

Edit: since [@DSM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146290/plotting-a-line-over-several-graphs/6147154#6147154) was so much better than mine I have shamefully incorporated some of that answer in an attempt to make my answer less poor.

I've tried to handle the somewhat-general case of multiple subplots in a column (i.e. not the even-more-general case of multiple subplots, e.g. in a grid).

Thanks, @DSM, for your answer and @Artium for the question.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def main():
    fig = plt.figure() 

    x = np.arange(20)
    y1 = np.cos(x)
    y2 = (x**2)
    y3 = (x**3)
    yn = (y1,y2,y3)
    cut = (x > 0) & (x % 2 == 0)
    COLORS = ('b','g','k')

    for i,y in enumerate(yn):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(len(yn),1,i+1)

        ax.plot(x, y,ls='solid', color=COLORS[i], zorder=1) 
        ax.scatter(x[cut], y[cut], c='r', zorder=2)

        if i != len(yn) - 1:
            ax.set_xticklabels( () )

        for j in x[cut]:
            if i != len(yn) - 1:
                ax.axvline(x=j, ymin=-1.2, ymax=1,
                           c='r', lw=2, zorder=0, clip_on=False)
            else:
                ax.axvline(x=j, ymin=0, ymax=1,
                           c='r', lw=2, zorder=0, clip_on=False)

    fig.suptitle('Matplotlib Vertical Line Example')
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image]

Comment: I really like your answer. However, in my case horizontal and vertical margins are present if I run your code. Any idea how to remove them?

Comment: To be more precise. In my case, the range of the xaxis is [-5,20] instead of [0,20] and f. e. for the last plot, the yaxis range is [-1000,8000] instead of [0,7000]. Tried almost anything (autoscale, tight axis, relim etc.) without success.

Comment: If someone else is interested: It is caused by the generation of the scatter points.

Comment: why xticklabels have a weird input ()?

Answer (score 12):

**[Update 03/2013]** In newer revisions of matplotlib, there's [ConnectionPatch](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/text/annotations.html#using-connectionpatch) that greatly simplifies this task. It's particularly useful whenever there are more than two subplots that need to be covered.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import ConnectionPatch
from numpy import arange, sin, cos

xx = arange(100)
cut = (xx > 0) & (xx % 17 == 0)
y1 = sin(xx)
y2 = (xx**2) % 2.0+cos(xx+0.5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.plot(xx, y1, c="blue")
ax1.scatter(xx[cut], y1[cut], c="red")
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.plot(xx, y2, c="green")
ax2.scatter(xx[cut], y2[cut], c="red")

for x in xx[cut]:
    con = ConnectionPatch(xyA=(x, -1.5), xyB=(x, 1.5),
        coordsA="data", coordsB="data", axesA=ax2, axesB=ax1,
        arrowstyle="-", linewidth=2, color="red")
    ax2.add_artist(con)

plt.draw()
fig.savefig('pic.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try `axvline(x, y1, y2)` ([link](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline)), but I don't think any of the options in pyplot will draw something that spans across several subplots/graphs.

If that's the case, I would just try drawing the same vertical line at each point in the graph, hoping that the same intent is conveyed to the viewer.

Comment: Apologies. My answer doesn't present any new information that yours doesn't have. I had already put together an example so I thought that I would post anyway. +1 to you for being much faster.

Comment: agreed with Jonathan, an answer with source code and examples is much better than one without, speed doesn't count!

Comment: If I try your way, the line is hidden behind the inset axis set. What am I doing wrong?