# Plotting a line in between subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a plot in Python with Pyplot that have multiple subplots.

I would like to draw a line which is not on any of the plots. I know how to draw a line which is part of a plot, but I don't know how to do it on the white space between the plots.

Thank you.

---

Thank you for the link but I don't want vertical lines between the plots. It is in fact a horizontal line above one of the plots to denote a certain range. Is there not a way to draw an arbitrary line on top of a figure?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146290/plotting-a-line-over-several-graphs/6147154#6147154) the kind of thing you're thinking of?  If so, then `clip_on=False` may help.

Comment: You can use "manual coordinates", respective to the whole plot, to add shapes to the figure. That would be coordinates from 0 and 1 relative to figure height and width. I've seen that already (but don't remember how, will take a look).

Comment: `annotate` is also very useful for this purpose

Answer (score 3):

First off, a quick way to do this is jut to use `axvspan` with y-coordinates greater than 1 and `clip_on=False`. It draws a rectangle rather than a line, though.

As a simple example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))
ax.axvspan(2, 4, 1.05, 1.1, clip_on=False)
plt.show()
```

[image]

For drawing lines, you just specify the `transform` that you'd like to use as a kwarg to `plot` (the same applies to most other plotting commands, actually).

To draw in "axes" coordinates (e.g. 0,0 is the bottom left of the axes, 1,1 is the top right), use `transform=ax.transAxes`, and to draw in figure coordinates (e.g. 0,0 is the bottom left of the figure window, while 1,1 is the top right) use `transform=fig.transFigure`.

As @tcaswell mentioned, `annotate` makes this a bit simpler for placing text, and can be very useful for annotations, arrows, labels, etc.  You could do this with annotate (by drawing a line between a point and a blank string), but if you just want to draw a line, it's simpler not to.

For what it sounds like you're wanting to do, though, you might want to do things a bit differently.

It's easy to create a transform where the x-coordinates use one transformation and the y-coordinates use a different one. This is what `axhspan` and `axvspan` do behind the scenes.  It's very handy for something like what you want, where the y-coordinates are fixed in axes coords, and the x-coordinates reflect a particular position in data coords.

The following example illustrates the difference between just drawing in axes coordinates and using a "blended" transform instead. Try panning/zooming both subplots, and notice what happens.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import blended_transform_factory

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

# Plot a line starting at 30% of the width of the axes and ending at
# 70% of the width, placed 10% above the top of the axes.
ax1.plot([0.3, 0.7], [1.1, 1.1], transform=ax1.transAxes, clip_on=False)

# Now, we'll plot a line where the x-coordinates are in "data" coords and the
# y-coordinates are in "axes" coords.
# Try panning/zooming this plot and compare to what happens to the first plot.
trans = blended_transform_factory(ax2.transData, ax2.transAxes)
ax2.plot([0.3, 0.7], [1.1, 1.1], transform=trans, clip_on=False)

# Reset the limits of the second plot for easier comparison
ax2.axis([0, 1, 0, 1])

plt.show()
```

### Before panning

[image]

### After panning

[image]

Notice that with the bottom plot (which uses a "blended" transform), the line is in data coordinates and moves with the new axes extents, while the top line is in axes coordinates and stays fixed.

Comment: It's also possible to use `ax.hlines(1.1, 0.3, 0.7, clip_on=False, transform=ax.transAxes)` although this is essentially what you are doing with the `plot` method. At least I think it is more intuitive to use this method rather than `plot` when intentionally drawing horizontal lines.