# How to add axvline on multiplegraph subplots( row,col )

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I want to add axvline on multiple graph. 
one grahp is work.but subpolt (row,column) not working
picture : [image: picture]

Multigraph : [image: picture]

mycode at below :

```
df[[10]].plot.kde(title="Dimentions : W2",legend=None)
plt.axvline(w2spec, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1,color='pink')
plt.axvline(w2lower, linestyle='solid', linewidth=1,color='darkgoldenrod')
plt.axvline(w2upper, linestyle='solid', linewidth=1,color='darkgoldenrod')



fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, ncols=4)
fig=plt.figure()

ax = df[[10]].plot.kde(figsize=(25,10),ax=axes[0, 0],title="Dimentions : W2",legend=None)
plt.axvline(w2spec, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1,color='pink')
plt.axvline(w2lower, linestyle='solid', linewidth=1,color='darkgoldenrod')
plt.axvline(w2upper, linestyle='solid', linewidth=1,color='darkgoldenrod')
ax = df[[11]].plot.kde(title="Dimentions : H2",ax=axes[1, 0],legend=None)
plt.axvline(h2spec, linestyle='dashed', linewidth=1,color='pink')
plt.axvline(h2lower, linestyle='solid', linewidth=1,color='darkgoldenrod')
plt.axvline(h2upper, linestyle='solid', linewidth=1,color='darkgoldenrod')
```

Comment: Try `ConnectionPatch` as seen in the second answer of this post or using the `clip_on` parameter as seen in the first one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146290/plotting-a-line-over-several-graphs

Comment: You would need to use `axes[0, 0].axvline(...)` to plot to one of the axes.

Comment: thankyou for answer